# how to run the NetOffice example?

Tags: debugging, netoffice

I'm checking NetOffice and trying to run a simple example from below:
https://github.com/NetOfficeFw/Samples/tree/master/Excel/02%20NetOffice%20Excel%20COMAddin%20Sample/01%20Simple

how can run this example in visual studio? ideally I think it should be opening a blank Excel which contains addin, but when debugging, it just an error "In order to debug this project , add an executable project to this solution...."
so what executable project I need to add?

thanks,

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this example, you must do two steps:

1. The add-in must be registered in the registry to load it when starting Excel.

This step is done automatically, when you built the add-in (this is part of the NetOffice "magic" with the *COMAddin* attribute).

You can do the registration of the add-in manually too by using *regasm.exe*.

2. Excel must be started so that the add-in is loaded and the debugger can be used.

I prefer to set this up in the project properties. Go in the project properties on the tab *Debug*, go on *Start external program* and select the path of the excel.exe on your computer.

You could also start Excel and attach the project debugging to the Excel process.

If you have done the two steps, then start debugging by clicking F5. Now Excel starts. If you set a breakpoint, then it should be reached either at the Excel starting process or when you open a workbook in Excel.